# How to read variables from passed over pointer of one object?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am passing object as pointer and then I want to use passed objects values to assign them to other method.

This is how I pass object:

```
Author *pAuthor = new Author("John", "Doe");
Publisher *pPublisher = new Publisher("Wrox", "10475 Crosspoint Blvd.", "Indianapolis");
Book *pBook = new Book("Memory Management", pAuthor, pPublisher, 39.99);

cout << pBook->getBookInfo() << endl;
```

Now, In other class I must read those passed variables from object and assign them somewhere else. In this code I am using only passed values and no object because I'm not sure how to deal with them.

```
Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    this->title = title;
    this->price = price;
}
```

How do I read passed values from passed object?

Edit, There might be some confusion in my question. The below code must access the variables and insert then into methods which will later use them.

Each variable I try to insert look like this. I don't want to access the author's private variables because no way I can acces when they are set private, and yet they are still empty.

The code I have right now is:

```
Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    this->title = title;
    this->price = price;

    author.setFirstName();
    author.setLastName();

    publisher.setName();
    publisher.setAddress();
    publisher.setCity();
}
```

Comment: `pAuthor->first`, `pPublisher->city`, etc.

Comment: @veer: That would work but my local variables are private.

Comment: @HelpNeeder, that's exactly as they should be, and it's exactly why you use getter and setter functions.

Comment: @HelpNeeder you can make them `friend`s, though I don't necessarily advocate it in this case.

Comment: @mah I don't think accessors and mutators should be used if they only consist of `return this->member;` and `this->member = val;` respectively

Comment: @veer you're free to have that opinion of course, but it's generally disagreed with. In your limited example there's not any real difference, but when you go beyond the homework level, you also allow those functions to limit the values being set, validate them, etc. It's better to be in the habit of just doing it that way all the time, to save yourself problems later. This is the essence of object oriented programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax, supposing you have these variables and they are public.

```
pAuthor->first_name ;
pAuthor->last_name ;
```

And for other class.

```
pPublisher->author ;
pPublisher->name ;
pPublisher->place ;
```

The `'->'` operator dereferences pointer to the object, or in other words, takes you to your desired variables.

It is better if you use these data members as private members. If you do so, you cannot access them directly. You would have to use getter and setter functions to read and write their values.

They would look like this.

```
pAuthor->getfirst_name() ;
pAuthor->getlast_name() ;

pPublisher->getauthor() ;
pPublisher->getname() ;
pPublisher->getplace() ;
```

Lastly it is better if you dont pass by value these object. Pass them by reference and use `const` before them.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you provide "getter" and "setter" functions in your object definitions, and use them.

Answer (score 2):

You pass in a pointer to an object and through that pointer you can call any public methods of that class. Like this

```
 pAuthor->public_member_function();
```

You will need to implement the functions of class `Author` to allow other classes to access the data that you want to be able to retrieve